# how to retrieve data from fire base and assign to a string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database in fire-base. In that I have a child node named "item1", under item1 i have two values

1. name
2. prize

I want to retrieve the name of item1 and I want to put it in a string called "foodname". How can I do that?

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("menu");
```

Here I tried but did not find solution

```
String foodname; //this string should get the value as "diary milk"
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     }
 });
```

[image: image of database]

Comment: `mDatabase.child("item1").child("name").addValueEventListener...` `foodname = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)`

Comment: can i ask one more question if i have more than one items how can i store these ? by using an array ? or something else ? can you please help me

Comment: you can create your own class item that contains 2 strings and make query like `mDatabase..addValueEventListener...` and `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { MyItem item =  dataSnapshot.getValue(MyItem.class) }`

Comment: like in example - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mDatabase.child("menu").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         //This will loop through all items. Add variables to arrays or lists as required
         for (DatasnapShot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
         {
             foodname = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
             String prize = dataSnapshot.child("prize").getValue().toString();
         }


     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     }
 });
```

You can fetch each child individually like such. Or you can make use of a Model or a Hashmap to fetch all of the data and then fetch the data you would like based on the Key

Comment: can i ask one more question if i have more than one items how can i store these ? by using an array ? or something else ? can you please help me

Comment: Please see edit above. Does this answer your question? I just assumed you wanted prize as a String. You don't need to convert it like that

Comment: Thank you @AliAhmed for pointing that out. I have corrected the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using below code you can get `food name`

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("menu");

  mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   String foodName = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                   String foodPrice = snapshot.child("prize").getValue().toString();        
               }
          }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
 });
```

Comment: can i ask one more question if i have more than one items how can i store these ? by using an array ? or something else ? can you please help me

Comment: yes you can use this code to save all food name in String array

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving any data from Firebase requires a correct database reference and `eventListeners` that can work for what you want.

To know more about `eventListeners` [visit this link.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("menu").child("item1");

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
// this code will get only details from item1
                   foodname = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                   String price = dataSnapshot.child("prize").getValue(Integer.class);

//if you want details from multiple items, you have to loop over the child nodes like this

                   for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       foodname = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                       String price = snapshot.child("prize").getValue().toString();        
                   }

              }
              @Override
              public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
        });
```